# Execute the Python File within the Folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a .py file to execute within a folder

I tried to open text file and it did work when I'm trying to open a .py file it didn't work

```
import os
os.popen("myfolder\\run.txt")
```

it works but when I try to below code to run a .py file like

```
import os
os.popen("myfolder\\run.py")
```

it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your trying to execute the python file that's in a folder, you need to switch your directory to that folder.

To do that, do:

```
os.chdir('myfolder')
```

Next, to execute the .py file, do:

```
os.system('python run.py')
```

Altogether, this code should work:

```
import os
os.chdir('myfolder')
os.system('python run.py')
```

This code should run the `run.py` file.

Comment: python: can't open file 'ZZ': [Errno 2] No such file or directory